# How to merge two flutter projects?

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app where in which i want to add an existing project, to the main app and when i made changes to the existing app it will be reflected in the main app.

I have found that it can done by the making app package in flutter , but my project is very large it cannot be done in this way so is there any other way to do so.

Comment: Which platform(s) are you targeting? Are you trying to integrate the Flutter runtime into an existing native project (iOS, Android or something else), or are you just looking to create a different variation of your existing Flutter app?

Comment: just creating diffrent variation of existing flutter app .

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create a variation of an existing Flutter app (with both shared and separate code & resources depending on where you need them), then most likely what you're looking for are *product flavors*.

The official Flutter documentation is a great place to start as it also links quite a lot of detailed tutorials on this topic: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors

Comment: flavors creates different version of the  project and can be used in the same project , this is not what iam looking for , i want to create a separate project, while using the exsiting project that i have already created .

Comment: but thanks for your effort